# What is the Taylor Series for $f(x)=\ln(x)$. For what range of $x$ is it valid?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Tip given: Find the integration that equals $f(x)$

I have worked out the derivatives but I am not sure what x value to evaluate the series at. $x=1$ or $x=2$ is what I am thinking but which one would be a better estimate.

I am not quite sure on finding validity as I feel it is using the ratio test but I didn't understand it quite well, it will be helpful if someone could explain it be a little bit more.

Thank you

Comment: If you know Taylor series for $1/x$, integrate it. 

If that's a homework assignment, you should be told at which point to evaluate the series. My bet is on $x=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a>0$, then 
$$
\frac{1}{x+a}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^n}{a^{n+1}}
$$
then integrating 
$$
\ln(x+a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{a^{n+1}}+C
$$
then plugging in $x=0$ finds $C$ to be $\log (a)$, so you have 
$$
\ln(x+a)=\ln(a)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{x^n}{a^{n}}
$$
which converges as long as 
$$
|x|<a
$$
by Cauchy-Hadamard or noting that integrating does not affect the radius of convergence.